# Not able to remove null from a list in Java

Tags: java

I have a list of a bean class newSRMAPIResponseBeanList wherein I am always getting a null object at last which I am trying to remove but it is resulting in null pointer exception if I handle the exception, it is not removing that null value. Below is my code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newSRMAPIResponseBeanList.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    if (newSRMAPIResponseBeanList.get(i).getCompanyId().equals(null)) {
                        newSRMAPIResponseBeanList.remove(i);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

In the if condition itself it is failing. I want to remove the null value of company ID. Actually newSRMAPIResponseBeanList is a list of `List<NewSRMAPIResponseBean> newSRMAPIResponseBeanList = new ArrayList<>();` and the bean class is as follows.

```
public class NewSRMAPIResponseBean {
    private String companyId;
    private String investmentId;
    private String performanceId;
    private List<String> values;
}
```

Is there any way I can remove that null value? I also tried using Java streams as follows.

```
List<NewSRMAPIResponseBean> finalList=newSRMAPIResponseBeanList.parallelStream()
                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This too did not work.

Comment: Please post the complete error-output (including stack trace) for "resulting in null pointer exception", also show what did not work when filtering with Java's Streaming API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove the null value of company ID.

I presume you mean remove the list element if the Id is null. So It's not the bean that is null, it is the `companyId`.  Assuming you have getters, try it like this.  If the Id is not null, let it pass thru.

```
List<NewSRMAPIResponseBean> finalList=newSRMAPIResponseBeanList.parallelStream()
        .filter(bean->bean.getCompanyId() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also do it in a simple loop.
To avoid a `ConurrentModificationException`, use an iterator.

```
Iterator<NewSRMAPIResponseBean> iter =  newSRMAPIResponseBeanList.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next().getCompanyId() == null) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```